# Unable to use button in datalist control

Tags: html, asp.net, eval

Not able to use button as a child control inside the datalist. Read a lot of articles which had no space between server and text but here it is not the scene
**Error:**Server tag not formatted

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DataList ID="datalist1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Delete eno ename
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
error in this line  <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("eno") %>"/>
                    <%#Eval("eno") %>
                    <%#Eval("ename") %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: check my post i send you the soulution

Answer (score 0):

In this case it might be easier to set the text property of the button on the server in the page load event.

Also why you are using this 
      <%#Eval("eno") %>
      <%#Eval("ename") %>

try this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DataList ID="datalist1" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Delete eno ename
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("eno") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Double quotes from the

`Text="<%#Eval("eno") %>"`

make it

`Text='<%#Eval("eno") %>'`
then it will work

wherever you use the

```
'<%#Eval() %>'
```

or

```
'<%#Bind() %>'
```

use it with the single quotes

Thanks :D